# Adding(mathwise) rows of several csv files in python

Tags: python, file, function, math, csv

I have csv files with the same headers (first row and first column contain said headers). The rest of the cells contain numbers. I need to take another csv file and add the numbers from the two csv files together. Is there any way to do this with the csv function in python?

Thanks

Comment: I just started I haven't been able to find anything on it. I don't know if the CSV function would work. I was thinking about placing the contents into a list and adding them then writing it back into a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
f = csv.reader(open('filename1.csv', 'rb'))
g = csv.reader(open('filename2.csv', 'rb'))
output = csv.writer(open('ouputfile.csv', 'wb'))
for row_f in f:
    row_g = g.next()
    row_output = list()
    for argi, item in enumerate(row_f):
        try:
            row_output.append(int(item) + int(row_g[argi]))
        except ValueError, e:
            pass
    output.writerow(row_output)
```

This assumes that both file1 and file2 have the same dimensions.  You can play around with it abit to get the functionallity you desire, but I think that this may be a decent starting point?

Comment: Everything seems to work but the CSV file I write my output to is blank. ANy ideas?